# Android Studio - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /abc.csv open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-studio, csv, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I am trying to read a CSV file, load its content to a spinner. I have given relevant permissions **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** to read a file from external storage. I have placed the CSV file in a directory requested permission on runtime. Also the file.exists() function return true but still unable to read csv file. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the error log:

```
022-02-27 18:03:32.457 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Khidmah/input.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:115)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at com.example.locationfetcher_v2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:157)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8157)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8129)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3494)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3693)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2135)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.461 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8059)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7932)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
2022-02-27 18:03:32.462 13080-13080/com.example.locationfetcher_v2 W/System.err:    ... 19 more
```

Below is my code:

```
            @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    //Using Dexter Library
    Dexter.withContext(this)
                    .withPermissions(
                            Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                    ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {/* ... */}
                @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
            }).check();
    
    
            MultiplePermissionsListener dialogMultiplePermissionsListener =
                    DialogOnAnyDeniedMultiplePermissionsListener.Builder
                            .withContext(this)
                            .withTitle("Camera, Storage and Location permission")
                            .withMessage("All Camera, Storage and Location permission are required for this application")
                            .withButtonText(android.R.string.ok)
                            .build();
    
            
         //// Read data from CSV file
        List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
        Spinner address_spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerAddress);

//        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Khidmah/", "input.csv");
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "input.csv");

        show_notification(file.getPath());
        show_notification(new Boolean(file.exists()).toString());
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            if (file.exists()){

                show_notification("can read - " + new Boolean(file.canRead()).toString());

                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.toURI().toString()));

                show_notification("successfully read file...");
                String[] nextLine;
                while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
//                    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + nextLine[2]);
                    addresses.add(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + nextLine[2]);
                    show_notification(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + nextLine[2]);
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,addresses);
                address_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CsvValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
                }
```

Here is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.locationfetcher_v2">

    <!-- Always include this permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Include only if your app benefits from precise location access. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LocationFetcher_v2"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

**UPDATE**

I am now using Dexter Library to grant permissions. I have added additional permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and place the input.csv file in Public Directory i.e. Downloads folder. However now it's giving following error:

```
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: You can read `Permission denied`. After File.exists() use File.canRead() before you act on the file.

Comment: The function returned False, how do I give it further permissions

Comment: You cant. One does not give permissions. One requests permissions. You can go for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE requesting 'all files access' or let the user choose the file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: I added permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but still same issue

Comment: Can you please elaborate ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT use.

Comment: `added permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` If you only added that to manifest then indeed that has no effect. And i have no idea what i should elaborate.

Comment: @blackapps I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: `requested permission on runtime. ` How many? You have three entries in manifest. Also try File.canRead() before you try to read a file.

Comment: `I have given relevant permissions` I have told you that you cannot give permissions. Please reread my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After File.exists() use File.canRead() before you act on the file.

This csv file is not created by your app.

Hence on Android 11 you are not the owner and although your app can check if the file exists it discovers with File.canRead() that the file is not accessable.

With MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and the right runtime code your app can obtain access.

The right code would start an intent for `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`.

Comment: I have already given that permission at runtime but still it is not accessible

Comment: You cannot give permission. This is the third time i tell you. But you can ask the user at runtime to give permission. Then you did it wrong. Please show your code to obtain 'all files access'.

Comment: I have already updated my question, in onCreate function I am using Dexter library to get permission. When the app is launched the first time it asks all the permissions

Comment: But still the issue persist

Comment: I do not know Dexter but it looks it cannot handle MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Better try without Dexter and in the normal way. Please show your new code.

Comment: It is updated in my question

Comment: ??? No. You still mess around with Dexter for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Please read my answer. You should start an intent for `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION.`

Comment: It's working, thanks